# Assign C++ Array to ROS Msg Array

Tags: ros, array, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I assign a C++ array to a ROS message array? In particular, how do I do this for a **float64[9]** array?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232659/assign-c++-array-to-ros-msg-array/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The std_msgs/Float64MultiArray message should do what you want:

http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64MultiArray.html

The message structure has a single field called `data` which can be treated as a `std::vector<double>` type in your C++ node.  If you know it will be a fixed array of 9 values, just allocate 9 elements in the vector after declaring the message variable:

```
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray array_msg;
array_msg.data.resize(9);
```

You can then publish and subscribe to a topic to transmit array messages between your nodes.

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2016-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0